# Mensagem de erro ao abrir arquivo excel exportado em PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

uso o seguinte código:

```
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Matemática');

    //set cell A1 content with some text
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $opcao);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', '#');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B2', 'REGIONAL');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C2', 'TURMAS');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F2', 'ESTUDANTES');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I2', 'MÉDIA DE ESTUDANTES AVALIADOS POR DISCIPLINA');
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J2', 'PERCENTUAL DE ACERTOS POR DISCIPLINAS(%)');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', 'TOTAL DE TURMAS');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', 'TURMAS COM RESULTADOS PROCESSADOS');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E3', '%');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F3', 'TOTAL DE ESTUDANTES');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G3', 'ESTUDANTES COM RESULTADOS PROCESSADOS');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H3', '%');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $linha, 'TOTAL GERAL');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A2:A3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:B3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C2:E2');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F2:H2');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I2:I3');
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J2:J3');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(4);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(45);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(16);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(8);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(16);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(8);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(22);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(18);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:I2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:I2')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3:H3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3:H3')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);

    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('2')->setRowHeight(45);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFC0C0C0');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:I2')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFD3D3D3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3:H3')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFD3D3D3');

    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),
            )
        )
    );

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:I2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:I3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Y3:I3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$linha.':I' .$linha)->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    $total_acertos = 0;
    $pontuacao_maxima = 0;
    $porcentagem_acerto = 0;
    $porcentagem_acerto_total = 0;
    $pontuacao_maxima_total = 0;
    $soma_total_acertos = 0;
    $pontuacao_maxima_total = 0;
    $quantidade_de_alunos = 0;
    $rowNumber = 4;
    $contador = 1;

    foreach ($totalizacao as $row) {

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $contador);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   


        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $row->nome);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, $row->quantidade_de_turmas);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowNumber, $row->quantidade_de_turmas_com_avaliacao);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $turma_porcent = 0;
        if ((int) $row->quantidade_de_turmas > 0) $turma_porcent = ((int) $row->quantidade_de_turmas_com_avaliacao / (int) $row->quantidade_de_turmas) * 100; else $turma_porcent = 0;
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowNumber, number_format($turma_porcent, 2, '.', '') .'%');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowNumber, $row->quantidade_de_alunos);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowNumber, $row->quantidade_de_alunos_processados);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $alunos_porcent = 0;
        if ($row->quantidade_de_alunos > 0) $alunos_porcent = ((int) $row->quantidade_de_alunos_processados / (int) $row->quantidade_de_alunos) * 100; else $alunos_porcent = 0;
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowNumber, number_format($alunos_porcent, 2, '.', '') . "%");
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $media_estudantes = 0;
        if ($row->quantidade_de_turmas_com_avaliacao > 0) $media_estudantes = number_format(((int) $row->quantidade_de_alunos_processados / $row->quantidade_de_turmas_com_avaliacao), 2, '.', ''); else $media_estudantes = 0;
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowNumber, $media_estudantes);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


        /* $pontuacao_maxima = $row->quantidade_de_alunos_processados * 20;
        $total_acertos    = (int) $row->quantidade_de_acertos_por_cre;
        $porcentagem_acerto = ($pontuacao_maxima > 0 ? round(($total_acertos / $pontuacao_maxima) * 100, 2) : '0');
        $porcentagem_acerto = $porcentagem_acerto.'%';
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowNumber, $porcentagem_acerto);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowNumber)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowNumber)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);*/


        $soma_total_acertos += $total_acertos;            
        $quantidade_de_turma_cons = $quantidade_de_turma_cons + $row->quantidade_de_turmas_com_avaliacao;
        $quantidade_de_turma      = $quantidade_de_turma + $row->quantidade_de_turmas;

        $quantidade_de_alunos     = $quantidade_de_alunos + $row->quantidade_de_alunos;
        $quantidde_de_alunos_proc = $quantidde_de_alunos_proc + $row->quantidade_de_alunos_processados;
        $quantidade_acertos       = $quantidade_acertos + $total_acertos;

        $rowNumber++;
        $contador++;
    }

    unset($styleArray);

     # % Turmas consolidadas
    $perc_total_turma = "0%";
    $perc_total_alunos = "0%";
    $perc_quantidade_acertos = "0%";

    if($quantidade_de_turma > 0)
    {
        $perc_total_turma = ($quantidade_de_turma_cons * 100) / $quantidade_de_turma;
        $perc_total_turma = number_format($perc_total_turma, 2, '.', '') . "%"; //round($perc_total_turma, 2) . "%";
    }

    if($quantidade_de_alunos > 0)
    {
        $perc_total_alunos = ($quantidde_de_alunos_proc * 100) / $quantidade_de_alunos;
        $perc_total_alunos = number_format($perc_total_alunos, 2, '.', '') . "%";
    }

    if($quantidade_de_turma_cons)
    {
        $quantidade_media_estudantes = $quantidde_de_alunos_proc / $quantidade_de_turma_cons;
        $quantidade_media_estudantes = number_format($quantidade_media_estudantes, 2, '.', '');
    }

    if($quantidde_de_alunos_proc > 0)
    {
        $perc_quantidade_acertos = ($quantidade_acertos * 100) / ($quantidde_de_alunos_proc * 20);
        $perc_quantidade_acertos = number_format($perc_quantidade_acertos, 2, '.', '') . "%";
    }

    $linhaAnt = $linha - 1;

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C".$linha, "=SUM(C3:C".$linhaAnt.")");
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D".$linha, "=SUM(D3:D".$linhaAnt.")");
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E".$linha, $perc_total_turma);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F".$linha, "=SUM(F3:F".$linhaAnt.")");
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("G".$linha, "=SUM(G3:G".$linhaAnt.")");
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("H".$linha, $perc_total_alunos);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("I".$linha, $quantidade_media_estudantes);
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("J19", $perc_quantidade_acertos);


    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$linha.':I'.$linha)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFD3D3D3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$linha.':I'.$linha)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

    //change the font size
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(20);

    //make the font become bold
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    //merge cell A1 until D1
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:I1');

    //set aligment to center for that merged cell (A1 to D1)
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


    $modalidade_arq = $_SESSION['modalidade'];
    $modalidade_arq = ($modalidade_arq == 'medio') ? 'EM' : 'EF';

    $filename= 'CONSOLIDAÇÃO DAS TURMAS - MATEMÁTICA (' . $modalidade_arq . ' ' . $this->session->userdata('ano') . ') - '.date("d.m.Y").'.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(1, 5);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G2')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G3')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G4')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G2:G4')->getAlignment()->setIndent(1);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2:I4')->getAlignment()->setIndent(1);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'PROJETO TELECURSO MG');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G2', 'TURMAS');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G3', 'MODALIDADE');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G4', 'DATA DE REFERÊNCIA');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I2', $this->session->userdata('ano'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I3', $modalidade);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I4', date("d/m/Y"));
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1:J1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFC0C0C0');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1:J1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G1:J1');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G2:H2');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G3:H3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G4:H4');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I1:J1');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I2:J2');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I3:J3');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I4:J4');


    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->getFont()->setSize(20);

    $styleArray = array(
      'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
          'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
          'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),
        )
      )
    );  

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1:J1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G2:J2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G3:J3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G4:J4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Ao abrir é mostrado a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após clicar em "SIM", na planilha em algumas colunas esta mostrando o resultado como 0.

Mas após clicar no botão "Habilitar Edição" do excel, os valores são mostrados e uma outra mensagem e mostrada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei várias soluções para as mensagens não serem mostradas e nada ainda. Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que possa ser? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O problema acontece porque a forma como você gera o arquivo leva a um XML inválido (como diz a mensagem de erro).

Arquivos xlsx são, internamente, coleções de arquivos XML. Para solucionar o seu problema, você deve gerar um arquivo com o seu código e renomeá-lo para que a extensão seja `.zip.` Você poderá então abrir esse arquivo e navegar para o caminho indicado no diálogo de reparos (`xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`).

Você precia abrir esse arquivo ("sheet1.xml") com algum programa capaz de validar XML, e verificar por que o XML está inválido. Só então você saberá qual ou quais células o seu código preenche de forma errada.

O código que você postou é muito grande e complexo, e provavelmente deve preencher corretamente a maior parte das células. Por isso recomendo que, após descobrir quais células são preenchidas com XML inválido, edite o código na pergunta para conter apenas o preenchimento das células que ficam inválidas.

Comment: Valeu Renan! Consegui resolver.